# net current direction in a pn junction?

Tags: diodes, pn-junction

in forward bias, when the holes enter the n-region and when the electrons enter the p-region, the recombination happens and the carriers annihilate each other.
so how does the net current generate?
on the other hand the direction of electrons and holes flow is opposite, i would like to know what is the direction of net current?

Answer (score 1):

I'll just steal a diagram from the web so we know what we're talking about:

[image]

(Image source: [circuitstoday.com](http://www.circuitstoday.com/pn-junction-diode-characteristics))

In forward bias, holes are injected from the p-region to the n-region and then diffuse from left to right. That means current is flowing from left to right in the n-region.

Electrons are injected from the n-region to the p-region and diffuse from right to left. Since electrons have negative charge, this means conventional current is flowing from left to right, the same as it is in the n-region.

In each region the injected minority carriers recombine with the much more numerous majority carriers. A tiny average drift of the majority carriers to "fill in" where a tiny fraction of them have recombined is enough to maintain a continuous current through the whole structure.

Comment: so the final current is the result of drift current or diffusion?

Comment: It's different in different parts of the diode, and it also depends on the dimensions of the diode. I'm assuming a "long-base" diode. Far away from the junction, it's majority carrier drift. Near the junction it's minority carrier diffusion. In the depletion region it's a behavior similar to thermionic emission (I'm not remembering the term used at the moment).